# iPad Application always starts in Portrait Mode

Tags: objective-c, orientation, startup

This might be a duplicate of a few thread, but the solution I found to solve this problem didn't work for me. My application is always starting in portrait mode, even though I have the next lines in my APP-Info.PList :

```
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Thanks for you help

[EDIT 1] To be clearer about the problem

The application actually starts up in landscape mode but when I log the size of the screen in the viewDidLoad method of the rootViewController, it gives me the sizes for portrait mode. This is the actual problem, because I would like to add a subview to the main view which size depends on the orientation of the screen. I hope I was clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your AppDelegate has the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` Method. If it returns YES then any orientation will be allowed.
Try this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    // Returns only Landscape Mode
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It still does not work. When I launch the application in landscape mode and log the size of the screen in the viewDidLoad method, it gives me WIDTH : 768.000000 / HEIGHT : 1004.000000 ...

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are not manually rotating the  uiview, if not check in the xib, the properties of the size inspector (i may be rotating but not adapting to the new size)

Comment: The size depends on the Orientation that is set in the Attribute Inspector of the view. But I don't want to set it to either Landscape or Portrait. I would like the app to detect the orientation of the iPad.

Comment: do you get the same on ViewWillAppear method?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this solved it for me:

```
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```